# Storing in BlobKeyProperty

Tags: python, webapp2

I have a model with a field called `testblob` which is a `BlobKeyProperty`.
I know that I need to store the data in a Blob, then get the key and save the key in my model's field `testblob`, but I can't understand the WebApp2 docs. They are missing an example, or I just can't see it.
How can I save a blob?

Comment: Where is the data supposed to be coming from? Are you uploading a file, or creating one programmatically?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Not really relevant for the question, but let's say I already have the binary representation of the file in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need GCS to store (write) data to the Blobstore. Here is an example using webapp2:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

If you do not want to use GCS, you have to send multipart/form-data to an upload url of the blobstore.